# Data not being passed to Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a Vue component receiving an array of 'items' from its parent.

I've sorted them into categories, two 'items' in each category:

```
computed: {
        // sort items into categories
        glass: function() {
            return this.items.filter(i => i.category === "glass").slice(0, 2);
        },
        ceramics:
        // etc...
```

I need to place both items in `categories.items` to then pass them as props to another component:

```
data() {
        return {
            categories: [
                { name: "Glass", sort: "glass", items: {} },
                { name: "Ceramics", sort: "ceramics", items: {} },
                { name: "Brass", sort: "brass", items: {} },
                { name: "Books/Comics", sort: "books", items: {} },
                { name: "Collectibles", sort: "collectibles", items: {} },
                { name: "Pictures", sort: "pictures", items: {} },
                { name: "Other", sort: "other", items: {} }
            ]
        };
    },
```

When I use `created` or `mounted` nothing is passed through, when I use `beforeDestroy` or `destroy` and `console.log` the results it works fine, but, they're of no use when exiting the page.

The 'items' are from an Axios GET request, could this be why?

GET request from parent component:

```
methods: {
        fetchItems() {
            // items request
            let uri = "http://localhost:8000/api/items";
            this.axios.get(uri).then(response => {
                // randomize response
                for (let i = response.data.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
                    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
                    [response.data[i], response.data[j]] = [
                        response.data[j],
                        response.data[i]
                    ];
                }

                this.items = response.data;
            });
        }
    },
```

Passing props to child component:

```
        <div
            class="items-container"
            v-for="category in categories"
            :key="category.name"
        >
            <router-link :to="'category.link'" class="category-names-home-link">
                <h2 class="category-names-home">{{ category.name }}</h2>
            </router-link>
            <router-link
                :to="'category.link'"
                class="home-view-all"
                @mouseover.native="expand"
                @mouseout.native="revert"
                >View All...</router-link
            >
            <div class="items">
                <!-- Pass to child component as props: -->
                <SubItem :item="categories.items" />
                <SubItem :item="categories.items" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356679/1823841) here to show the issue happening. For ajax call you can use any public API for showing dummy data. Also, don't add the full code in the demo. Only one computed property maybe.

Comment: how are you passing the data to the child? Can you post that?

Comment: Is the axios request finished before the child component is added to the page?  If not, the data isn't going to show up in created or mounted.

Comment: Edited to cut down computed and passing props to child component @RaduDiță @ palaѕн

Comment: @StevenB. I'm not sure, I use the 'items' in another component using ```created``` and it works just fine

Comment: Axios get request will have a delay but when 'this.items' is set then it should update the vue model. I would recommend copying the response to a local variable and not mutating the response object directly

Comment: @NathanS I've removed the randomize but it hasn't fixed the problem. The 'items' are making it through but somehow sorting them using ```computed``` and then using a method to push them into ```categories.items``` takes too long for them to make it to the child

Comment: note that `item` should be a prop form the `SubItem` component, not data

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet how do you mean?

Comment: If you pass info from a parent component in the child component those should be `props` , not `data` or `computed` https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet I'm passing data in the form of props in another component and just tried it with computed, both work fine. Unless I'm misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Don't bother adding the items to the categories, keep them separate
- Instead of multiple computeds, use one computed object hash to store all the filtered sets:

```js
computed: {
  filtered() {
    if (!this.items) return null;
    const filtered = {};
    this.items.forEach(item => {
      if (filtered[item.category]) {
        filtered[item.category].push(item);
      } else {
        filtered[item.category] = [item];
      }
    });
    return filtered;
  }
}
```

Result:

```js
{
'Glass': [ ... ],
'Ceramic': [ ... ]
...
}
```

In the template:

```html
<div>
   <div v-for="category in categories" :key="category.name">
      <div class="items" v-for="item in filtered[category.name]">
         <SubItem :item="item" />
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

You can use a `v-if` in the parent to prevent displaying anything until the data is loaded:

```html
<display v-if="items" :items="items"></display>
```

Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/7dn1bhzq/)

Comment: Only thing is this will list all items instead of just 2 per category.  Let me know if you need me to edit it for 2.  It will look slightly non-intuitive but no less effective.

Comment: It's not displaying anything for some reason, with or without the v-if. When I remove my Axios request and paste in your code it works, but the request is being used elsewhere just fine so I really have no idea what the issue is

Comment: Log the data before you set it to `this.items` and determine the difference between that and my pseudo-data.  Screenshot the console log and post a link here if you want

Comment: It logs an array of objects with keys like 'id', 'name' etc.

Comment: No idea.  If it has a `name` and `category` property on each object like in your examples, there would be no problem.  No errors in console either?  Just nothing at all?  Time to debug it I guess.

Comment: The only thing is, in the log, each object property is displayed like this: ```category: (...)``` and if I hover over the the brackets it says 'invoke property getter', no idea if that means anything...

Comment: Time to test all of your data, step by step, show each thing, figure out what would cause a v-if not to show, etc.

Comment: The way you used `item.category` was a string:  `i.category === "glass"`  but that `(...)` sounds like something else

Comment: If I do ```v-for="item in filtered.brass"``` it displays correctly

Comment: Oh if I do ```v-for="item in filtered[category.sort]"``` it works because the item's categories are different from their display name. You're a genius! Thank you for the help